# UICollectionView reload cells while rotating

Tags: ios6, reload, uicollectionview, cells

so I created my own custom layouts for my UICollectionView. When i rotate from portrait to landscape mode, some of the cells start to reload its content. I thought the layout just changes the positions of every cell not reload the content?

The content should only reload when i call reload Data on the collection view.

Any ideas to what might be going on?

Comment: Just a guess: since ```UICollectionView``` has a lot in common with ```UITableView``` I could image, that the table view behaviour applies also to collection views. ```UITableView``` overrides ```layoutSubview``` and calls ```reloadData``` on orientation changes. Maybe it's just not documented...

Answer (score 2):

Use `invalidateLayout` instead of `reloadData` on rotation, or override `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:` and return YES in your UICollectionViewLayout subclass.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    myCollectionView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are aiming for this, but here it goes:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
    [super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```